# build a dashboard in logs counting how many time each log appears

Tags: logging, grafana, grafana-loki, grafana-variable, logql

[Loki Log click the log screenshot attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v8fHC.png)
here i have get logs with this query

```
{namespace="health-helper-stg"} |json | line_format "{{.log}}"
```

There are multiple logs with different msg types from multiple apps.

So i need to get count of each msg type and its count in the grafana table. Because msg type is dynamically changing hardcore is not possible. for example:

```
msg "request completed"
msg     "ReceiveTokenService.getVoiceToken" 
msg     .............etc
```

So we want to get each msg types and count dynamically not always mention msg type in the query.

I'm using this query to get manually to build a table

```
sum by (app) (count_over_time({namespace="health-helper-stg"} |= "msg" |="ReceiveTokenService.getVoiceToken" [$__range]))
```

but need to get one by one for each msg type but it takes long time and values dynamically change when we update code.

Answer (score 0):

```
sum by (app, msg) (count_over_time({namespace="health-helper-stg"} | json | line_format "{{.log }}" | json | __error__!="JSONParserErr" [$__range] ))
```

here you can see sum by use for getting label (app and msg) so these values are together. count_over_time is provide specific condition within the function get count for time range. hence json use for change log style to readable contents. so i want to make  "{{.log }}"  to json format hence i took msg as labels so i add to sum by function. so it get all types of msg type and it counts in table . so i can select how many count for each msg type.

Answer (score 0):

your answer is right . However, you could simplify it to extract nested json field in 1 step.
here is an example how to extract nested field ([LogQL Analyzer](https://grafana.com/docs/loki/latest/logql/analyzer/?query=%7C%20json%20msg%3D%22log.msg%22%2Capp%3D%22app%22&line%5B%5D=%7B%22log%22%3A%7B%22msg%22%3A%22hello%22%7D%2C%20%22app%22%3A%22gateway%22%7D))
[image]

So, if we apply it to your query it will be :

```
sum by (app, msg) (count_over_time({namespace="health-helper-stg"} | json app="app",msg="log.msg" | __error__!="JSONParserErr" [$__range] ))
```

Comment: it is working but coudnt see the msg type instead it showing empty "" in msg type but shows all counts